# Cloud function that triggers when an anonymous user authenticates

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a welcome mail to a user that converted from an anonymous to a permanent user using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Prevously i followed [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js) sample code on github which sent an email when a user was created.

The sample code uses the hook onCreate:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
      const user = event.data; 
      const email = user.email; 

      ... send the email
});
```

This function would trigger when the anonymous user is created (which is not what i want, since at this time the user has no email specified).

When the anonymous user converts to a permanent user the onCreate does not trigger obviously, since the user is converted not created. What cloud function do i use that triggers when an anonymous user converts to a permanent user?

When looking at the firebase cloud function reference, specifically at the [namespace for Firebase Authentication functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder) i find that there are only two methods to work with, onCreate and onDelete. So what are my options?

Edit: I went and asked in the google group for Firebase and got this answer:

> Hey there, 
>   Thank you for your request. Please file an official request
>   via support channels: https://firebase.google.com/support/ You can use
>   real-time database or Firestore to set some flag from the client when
>   an anonymous user is upgraded and then listen to that node's changes
>   in Cloud Functions. This should get you the functionality you need.
>
> Best regards,

So basically could just create a custom listener for it.